# Как выполнить GZip-сжатие статического содержимого средствами IIS 7.0?

Tags: gzip, iis-7

Настройки выполнены в следующем виде:

> `C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Appcmd.exe set config -section:urlCompression -doStaticCompression:true`
>
> `C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Appcmd.exe set config -section:httpCompression -[name='gzip'].staticCompressionLevel:9`

Однако несмотря на то, что серверу отправляется запрос с `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, статика не сжимается (в ответе отсутствует Content-Encoding, да и содержимое передаётся в полном объёме). В чём здесь проблема?

Answer (score 1):

А если прописать прям в web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>    <dynamicTypes>      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>    </dynamicTypes>    <staticTypes>      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>    </staticTypes>  </httpCompression>  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/></system.webServer>
```